# I use Spring security version 6.2, but static resources are ignored

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, filter, spring-security

I upgraded the Spring Security version to 6.2 and set the security settings as follows.

```
@Bean
public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
    return (web) -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers(
                    "/h2-console/**",
                    "/static/**",
                    "/img/**",
                    "/css/**",
                    "/js/**",
                    "/images/**",
                    "/favicon.ico",
                    "/error",
                    "/**/**.jsp",
                    "/misc/**"
            )
```

And I used an interceptor to record the URL, but before uploading the version, only the URL for the screen was recorded.

After uploading the version

```
[https|GET][/static/js/placeholders.min.js]
[https|GET][/static/css/admin.css][200](00:00:00.031)
[https|GET][/static/js/jquery-3.7.1.min.js]
```

The following static resource URL is also recorded. Are the security settings incorrect, or is the static resource not ignored in the changed version?

CSS is applied by ignoring static resources in the filter, but I am curious why /static request information is displayed in the interceptor.